# issue with kendo ui window in IE 11

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

When clicking button inside the Kendo popup window, the button just increasing the width and clicking is not working. below is my button

```
<td style="padding-left:10%;">
    <input type="button" onclick="onPopOKClick()" value="OK" class="k-button" style="height: 100%; width: 45%" id="btnOK">
</td
```

>
please provide a solution

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about a Kendo UI window? Also, there is not enough code in your example to troubleshoot the problem. When you say "the button just increasing the width" are you saying that when you click the button, the width of the popup is increasing?

Comment: when clicking the button, button width increasing, and click event is not working. If clicking again it is working..

Comment: again I need to see more code. This is not a standard problem that there is an answer for. It is specific to your code. Can you update your answer with `onPopOKClick()` code?

Comment: exactly jwatts. It is solved, problem was in css of container td.  I think Padding css doesn't allow % value. I changed to pixels.  Thanks alot for your attention.